# Cakephp Containable not attaching to Model

Tags: php, cakephp

I've used containable tons of times but I can not figure for the life of me why it is not working correctly now.

I have 3 models Project, User, and Country.

Project belongsTo User
User belongsTo Country

here is the models

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $displayField = 'username';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'AccountType' => array(
            'className' => 'AccountType',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_type_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'PaymentType' => array(
            'className' => 'PaymentType',
            'foreignKey' => 'payment_type_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'InstantMessenger' => array(
            'className' => 'InstantMessenger',
            'foreignKey' => 'instant_messenger_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'TimeZone' => array(
            'className' => 'TimeZone',
            'foreignKey' => 'time_zone_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Language' => array(
            'className' => 'Language',
            'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
}


<?php
class Project extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Project';
    var $displayField = 'project_title';

    var $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
                    'className' => 'User',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
            ),
            'ProjectType' => array(
                    'className' => 'ProjectType',
                    'foreignKey' => 'project_type_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
            ),
            'BiddingType' => array(
                    'className' => 'BiddingType',
                    'foreignKey' => 'bidding_type_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
            ),
            'ProjectStatus' => array(
                    'className' => 'ProjectStatus',
                    'foreignKey' => 'project_status',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
            ),
            'EmploymentType',
            'PaymentType',
    );
}



<?php
class Country extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Country';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    var $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Now here is my code to try to attach a containable to project and add User

```
function smartbid($projid = null)
{
    $this->loadModel('Content');
    $content = $this->Content->findById(53);
    $this->set('content',$content);
    $this->Project->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    $options = array(
       array(
        'conditions'=>
           array(
                'Project.id'=>$projid
            ),
           'contain'=>array(
               'User'
           )
        ) 
     );
    $project = $this->Project->find('first',$options);

    $this->set(compact('project'));
}
```

Now cakephp completely ignores my attached containable and returns this

```
Array
(
    [Project] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 19
            [status] => 1
            [approval_status] => 0
            [project_status] => 2
            [approval_date] => 2012-02-08
            [project_title] => Database Reporting
            [project_type_id] => 3
            [budget] => 100
            [bidding_type_id] => 1
            [employment_type_id] => 
            [esl] => 1
            [secrecy] => 0
            [secrecy_file] => 
            [description] => this is my first post
            [performance] => 0
            [cme] => 6
            [files_share] => 
            [project_deadline] => 1
            [delivery_deadline] => 2012-02-16
            [bidding_deadline] => 2012-02-27
            [legal] => 1)Employer requires complete and fully-functional working program(s) in executable form as well as complete source code of all work done.

2) Deliverables must be in ready-to-run condition as follows (depending on the nature of the project and deliverables):

2a) If there are any server-side deliverables (intended to only exist in one place in the Employer's environment) then they must be installed by the Consultant in ready-to-run condition (unless specified elsewhere by the Employer).

2b) All other software (including but not limited to any desktop software or software the Employer intends to distribute) must include a software installation package that will install the software in ready-to-run condition on the platform(s) specified in this project (unless specified elsewhere by the Employer).

3) All deliverables will be considered 'work made for hire' under U.S. Copyright law. Employer will receive exclusive and complete copyrights to all work purchased.

3b) No part of the deliverable may contain any copyright restricted 3rd party components (including GPL, GNU, Copyleft, etc.) unless all copyright ramifications are explained AND AGREED TO by the Employer on the site per the Consultant's Worker Legal Agreement.
            [close] => 0
            [agree] => 1
            [created] => 2012-02-06
            [top_employer] => 0
            [view_counter] => 41
            [pause_deadline] => 
            [payment_type_id] => 
            [status_date] => 2012-02-08
            [redeem_amount] => 
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [username] => EmployerWarrior
            [password] => 7c6a180b36896a0a8c02787eeafb0e4c
            [account_type_id] => 2
            [picture] => 
            [resume] => 
            [alert] => 0
            [first_name] => Yaser
            [last_name] => Ibrahim
            [company_name] => Software Momentum, Inc.
            [company_incorporated] => 1
            [email] => Yaser43082@hotmail.com
            [address] => 123 Somewhere
            [apartment_number] => 
            [city] => Some City
            [state] => Some State
            [country_id] => 1
            [phone_city] => 614
            [phone_country] => 1
            [phone_number] => 1234567
            [fax_city] => 
            [fax_country] => 
            [fax_number] => 
            [instant_messenger_id] => 1
            [im_username] => 
            [postal] => 43082
            [time_zone_id] => 58
            [language_id] => 23
            [esl] => 1
            [us_resident] => 1
            [ssnum] => 1234567
            [have_ssnum] => 1
            [work_permit_number] => 
            [alien_number] => 
            [work_permit] => 0
            [green_card] => 0
            [payment_type_id] => 4
            [ip] => 
            [created] => 2012-02-06 08:59:35
            [top_employer] => 0
            [top_consultant] => 0
            [rating] => 0
            [money_invested] => 0
            [money_earned] => 0
            [total_projects] => 0
            [last_project] => 0
            [active] => 0
            [last_login] => 
            [last_seen] => 2012-02-26 14:13:08
            [is_logged_in] => 0
            [time_format_id] => 1
            [paypal_id] => 
            [momentum_expiration] => 2014-02-12
        )

    [ProjectType] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Small Business Project
            [min] => 100
            [max] => 499.99
            [order] => 4
        )

    [BiddingType] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => Public Bidding
            [percentage] => 15
        )

    [ProjectStatus] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [status] => Open Bids
            [icon] => bid_open.png
            [order] => 3
            [default] => 1
        )

    [EmploymentType] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => 
        )

    [PaymentType] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [type] => 
        )

    [BidWinner] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [comment_group_id] => 
            [bid_status_id] => 
            [project_id] => 
            [bid_amount] => 
            [performance_guaranteed] => 
            [isSmartBid] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [comment] => 
            [isWinner] => 
            [created] => 
        )

    [HRWWallet] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 19
            [account_type_id] => 
            [entity_id] => 1
            [payment_type_id] => 1
            [entity_type_id] => 1
            [payment_to_id] => 
            [payment_status_id] => 2
            [payment_number] => 
            [service_id] => 4
            [created] => 2012-02-10 18:45:52
            [description] => Payment for project
            [credit] => 100
            [debit] => 0
            [billing_address] => 
            [billing_city] => 
            [billing_state] => 
            [billing_country_id] => 
            [billing_name] => 
            [exp_year] => 
            [exp_month] => 
            [security_code] => 
        )

    [EmployerRating] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [owner_id] => 
            [project_id] => 
            [rated_by_id] => 
            [account_type_id] => 
            [rating] => 
            [comment] => 
            [created] => 
        )

    [ConsultantRating] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [owner_id] => 
            [project_id] => 
            [rated_by_id] => 
            [account_type_id] => 
            [rating] => 
            [comment] => 
            [created] => 
        )

    [Arbitration] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [project_id] => 1
            [defendent_id] => 20
            [plantiff_id] => 19
            [magistrate_id] => 17
            [arbitration_status_id] => 1
            [verdict] => 
            [created] => 2012-02-11 23:00:00
            [end] => 
        )

    [Bid] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [comment_group_id] => 1
                    [bid_status_id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [bid_amount] => 75
                    [performance_guaranteed] => 10
                    [isSmartBid] => 0
                    [user_id] => 20
                    [comment] => Hi, I was writing about your project
                    [isWinner] => 
                    [created] => 2012-02-08 14:15:04
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [comment_group_id] => 2
                    [bid_status_id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [bid_amount] => 100
                    [performance_guaranteed] => 25
                    [isSmartBid] => 0
                    [user_id] => 18
                    [comment] => I can do this work
                    [isWinner] => 
                    [created] => 2012-02-08 14:16:39
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [comment_group_id] => 2
                    [bid_status_id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [bid_amount] => 45
                    [performance_guaranteed] => 10
                    [isSmartBid] => 1
                    [user_id] => 18
                    [comment] => This is a smart bid bid
                    [isWinner] => 0
                    [created] => 2012-02-25 15:40:54
                )

        )

    [PaymentTransaction] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 19
                    [account_type_id] => 
                    [entity_id] => 1
                    [payment_type_id] => 1
                    [entity_type_id] => 1
                    [payment_to_id] => 
                    [payment_status_id] => 2
                    [payment_number] => 
                    [service_id] => 4
                    [created] => 2012-02-10 18:45:52
                    [description] => Payment for project
                    [credit] => 100
                    [debit] => 0
                    [billing_address] => 
                    [billing_city] => 
                    [billing_state] => 
                    [billing_country_id] => 
                    [billing_name] => 
                    [exp_year] => 
                    [exp_month] => 
                    [security_code] => 
                )

        )

    [WorkAcceptanceLog] => Array
        (
        )

    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [comment_group_id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 19
                    [from_id] => 20
                    [cc_id] => 
                    [isArbitration] => 
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Re:
                    [comment] => Hi, I was writing about your project
                    [created] => 2012-02-08 14:15:04
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [comment_group_id] => 2
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 19
                    [from_id] => 18
                    [cc_id] => 
                    [isArbitration] => 
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Re:
                    [comment] => I can do this work
                    [created] => 2012-02-08 14:16:39
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [comment_group_id] => 2
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 18
                    [from_id] => 19
                    [cc_id] => 
                    [isArbitration] => 
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Broadcasted Message
                    [comment] => This is a broadcast to all consultants in regards to the project.
                    [created] => 2012-02-08 14:18:52
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 2012-02-08 14:18:51
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [comment_group_id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 20
                    [from_id] => 19
                    [cc_id] => 
                    [isArbitration] => 
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Broadcasted Message
                    [comment] => This is a broadcast to all consultants in regards to the project.
                    [created] => 2012-02-08 14:18:52
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 2012-02-08 14:18:52
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [comment_group_id] => 0
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 19
                    [from_id] => 27
                    [cc_id] => 20
                    [isArbitration] => 1
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Arbitration
                    [comment] => What seems to be the issue ?
                    [created] => 2012-02-12 18:28:11
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [comment_group_id] => 5
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 17
                    [from_id] => 19
                    [cc_id] => 20
                    [isArbitration] => 1
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Arbitration
                    [comment] => Well I would like to say I am not happy
                    [created] => 2012-02-12 19:35:51
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [comment_group_id] => 6
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 17
                    [from_id] => 19
                    [cc_id] => 20
                    [isArbitration] => 1
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Arbitration
                    [comment] => I would like to make a complaint
                    [created] => 2012-02-12 22:07:08
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [comment_group_id] => 2
                    [project_id] => 1
                    [to_id] => 19
                    [from_id] => 18
                    [cc_id] => 
                    [isArbitration] => 
                    [no_contest] => 
                    [subject] => Re:Broadcasted Message
                    [comment] => This is a smart bid bid
                    [created] => 2012-02-25 15:40:54
                    [file_name] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [last_message] => 
                )

        )
```

)

as you can see it ignores my attachment. what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old question, but for what its worth.

[Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) is the documentation for the Containable Behavior.
It states that, to load the behavior on the fly, you should use:

```
$this->Model->Behaviors->load('Containable');
```

I believe the difference is merely due to the fact that `attach` and `detach` have been deprecated.

Also, why not just set the `$actAs` property in your model, or even in `AppModel`?

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actAs = array('Containable');
    // public $recursive = 0;
    //...
}
```

The relation with the `User` model defined in the `Project` model is missing the `foreignKey` field, which may cause trouble. I assume Cake defaults that to `user_id` which should of course be the name of the column in the `projects` table.

Other than that, your use of the `contain` options seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->Project->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$this->Project->contain(array(
            'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $projid),
            'User'));
$project = $this->Project->find('first');
$this->Project->Behaviors->detach('Containable');
```